# ¿Cómo saber la semana del año en base a la fecha ingresada?

Tags: java, date, netbeans-8.2

estoy haciendo un programa en java que te diga la semana del año en base a la fecha ingresada.
Ejemplo:

Entrada: 27/01.

Salida: La fecha ingresada pertenece a la semana 5 del año.

Use WEEK_OF_YEAR pero solo me da la semana actual del año.

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
String dia = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
String mes = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
String semanaanno = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
lblFecha.setText("semana del año: ".toUpperCase()+semanaanno;
```

Estoy usando este que solo muestra la fecha actual, pero yo quiero que me diga la semana del año conforme a una fecha que yo decida ingresar.

Comment: ¿Cómo has usado week of the year? Muestra el código que has probado para poder ayudarte, porque parece que no está cogiendo la fecha que le pasas. Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pero que pasa si a c le pones el dia que vos queres?

Comment: muestra lo que hay en el parametro, 
Si lo uso aqui String dia = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DATE)); muestra el dia del mes y 
 y de igual manera con 
String mes = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)); muestra mes acutal
String semanaanno = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)); semana del año actual

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar una instancia en base a la fecha que necesites utilizando `new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth)`

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2019, 04, 22);
String dia = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
String mes = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
String semanaanno = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
lblFecha.setText("semana del año: ".toUpperCase()+semanaanno;
```

Para los meses esta en `base 0`, por lo que 0 corresponde a enero.

Comment: gracas, si me sirvio

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como la correcta para que le pueda ayudar a otros

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de adaptar las fechas es con `SimpleDateFormat`, por ejemplo desde un formato de partida `dd/mm/aaaa`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      Calendar cl = Calendar. getInstance();

      System.out.println("Current week of year is : " +cl.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));

      SimpleDateFormat dateform = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      String sdate = "27/01/2020";
      try {

            Date date = dateform.parse(sdate);
            cl.setTime(date);
            System.out.println("Week of my date : " +cl.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Current week of year is : 18
Week of my date : 5
```

Comment: Gracias, si me sirvo pero me mostro un error diciendo: date.util no es compatible con date.sql
así que reemplace el Date date = dateform.parse(sdate);
por
java.util.Date date = dateform.parse(sdate);


igualmente funciono. Muchas gracias

Comment: @AlanHernández perfecto, siempre hay que adaptar a lo que tienes en tu proyecto. Si consideras que se ha contestado a la pregunta xf marca la respuesta para que no quede sin contestar.